# Ошибка с платежами telegram-bot, python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Нужно прикрутить яндекс кассу к телеграмм боту. Уже 2 день мучаюсь и без толку. Есть метод `send_invoice` для платежа:

```
bot.send_invoice(
        chat_id=m.chat.id,
        title='Пополнение счета',
        description='Описание',
        invoice_payload='true',
        provider_token=config.ya_token,
        start_parameter='true',
        currency='50',
        prices=[{'label': 'Оплата'}, {'amount': 50}]
    )
```

Он возвращает ошибку: `[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there should be at least one price"}']"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнём с того, что объект [LabeledPrice](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#labeledprice) - это объект, содержащий в себе два поля

1. **label**   *(String)*  - Portion label
2. **amount**  *(Integer)* - Price of the product in the smallest units of the currency (integer, not float/double). For example, for a price of US$ 1.45 pass amount = 145. See the exp parameter in currencies.json, it shows the number of digits past the decimal point for each currency (2 for the majority of currencies).

В запросе же [sendInvoice](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendinvoice), отправляемом пользователю и который должен представить ему выставляемый счёт, передаётся массив этих объектов (*параметр* `prices`). У вас же это массив непонятно чего. Попробуйте так:

```
bot.send_invoice(
        chat_id=m.chat.id,
        title='Пополнение счета',
        description='Описание',
        invoice_payload='true',
        provider_token=config.ya_token,
        start_parameter='true',
        currency='50',
        prices = [types.LabeledPrice(label='Working Time Machine', amount=50000), 
                  types.LabeledPrice('Gift wrapping', 15000)]
    )
```

---

Так же, следует обратить внимание на то, что **сумма должна быть целым числом и равняться количеству копеек**, а не рублей (*центов/долларов и т.п.*) и что  **минимальная сумма платежа должна быть эквивалентна $1**. То есть, если вы продаёте что-то за 50 рублей, то не сможете выставить счёт. Если вы продаёте что-то за 150 рублей, например, то поле `amount` параметра `prices` должно равняться 15000.
[Supported Currencies](https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#supported-currencies)