# Приём платежей от пользователей

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет. Возможнго, это вопрос не по шарпам, но так как пишу приложение на #, оставлю это здесь.
Я пишу бота для телеграм, который сможет принимать платежи быстро и удобно для юзера. Сейчас внутренними средствами бота можно реализовать эту задумку, использовав сбербанк или яндекс.кассу. Оба эти варианта мне не подходят. Начал копать в сторону апи яндекс денег, но там пока есть затыки, которые не победил. Может кто что посоветовать в этом вопросе, чтобы организовать приём платежей в боте малой кровью? 
П.с.: 
у каждого юзера есть свой уникальный айди, 
желательно принимать платежи с любых банковских карт, 
платежи должны приниматься в любой точке мира. 
Размер комиссии не принципиален. 
нужно принимать платежи без оформления юрлица

Answer (score 1):

Для приёма платежей используются провайдеры (*как вам уже известно, в РФ это Сбербанк и Яндекс.Касса*), без провайдера провести платёж с помощью Bot API невозможно. Провайдеров определяет сам Telegram по их заявкам, до определённого времени это был только Яндекс.

> желательно принимать платежи с любых банковских карт, платежи должны
>   приниматься в любой точке мира. Размер комиссии не принципиален. нужно
>   принимать платежи без оформления юрлица

Платёжный интерфейс Bot API позволяет это делать легко и удобно, запоминая данные карты пользователя, адрес доставки и тп. Вряд ли вы сможете реализовать всё это самостоятельно, потому что оно завязано на провайдера. Можно конечно нагородить каких-то костылей, типа отправки номера карты в чат и тд, но это дико. Тогда уж лучше криптой принимайте, если оформление ЮЛ (*хотя для этого и ИП сгодится*) является проблемой.

---

<sub>Так же по теме: [Ошибка с платежами telegram-bot, python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750190/183842)</sub>